# Music player server that works with pulseaudio out of the box

Tags: audio, music, ubuntu, media-player, unix

I would like to use a music player daemon along the lines of the program called ["Music player daemon"](https://www.musicpd.org/) (also known as "mpd") or [xmms2](https://xmms2.org/).

I mean something specific by "out of the box":

I am running Ubuntu.  Ubuntu uses pulseaudio.  I have my own pulse configuration, for reasons that aren't important here.

Neither of the programs I mention above support playing through pulseaudio without dependencies on the particular configuration of either pulseaudio, or the music server itself, or both.  Really I just want to run the daemon (probably as the same unix user that I use for all my other everyday purposes) and have it do whatever is appropriate to successfully talk to pulse using my current pulse configuration.  That is possible, because all other programs that I use to play sounds on my computer are able to play sound without special configuration.

Is there a program that meets that criterion?

Ideally there would also be an emacs mode to control it too, but that's just a wish, certainly not essential.